# “the” vs. “a/an” + clauses

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article, clauses

Here's the situation: I meet a friend and I tell her about yesterday:

> “Hey, John!”
>   “Hi, Sarah!”
>   “How was yesterday's trip?”
>   “It was great. Karl took me to the countryside to show me his new house. It reminded me of **the/a** house I rented in Oxford.”

“...**a** house I rented in Oxford.” indicates one of the (multiple) houses I rented in Oxford?
“...**the** house I rented in Oxford.” indicates I rented only one house in Oxford?

Comment: Your understanding of the difference is accurate. I don't think "a" would _necessarily_ indicate multiple houses, but it would definitely leave that option open. The "most correct" way to make that choice is exactly along the lines you've described.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung Just to make sure... I mean Sarah knows nothing of my life in Oxford and about Karl's house. I'm trying to figure those tricky cases in English when you use the definite article and yet for a listener, it's new information  so no shared knowledge no first mention. It's called postmodification as far as I know and works only with prepositional  and relative clauses

Answer (score 1):

Tyler James Young's comment really should be *an* answer - or it should be *the* answer :))

Common usage implies singular in both instances. But there are differences that can be subtle. Always consider the simple and most normal usage first.

So recall those grammar and usage lessons: "a" and "an" are the *indefinite* articles.  "The" is the *definite*.  The former can be general, the latter specific. Though this is generally true, the context can change this.

- I ate an apple.  [any apple]
- He ate the apple.  [ Hey! That *one* was my apple, buddy ! ]
- Adam ate the apple Eve gave him.  [ Really The only one like ever like that :) ]

So how to apply this to the houses in Oxford?

> It reminded me of ...
>
> *the* house I rented in Oxford.

The only **one** *you* rented there. (And, obviously, there's more than one house in that location.)

> a house I rented ...

You probably rented one only, but there are others you might have chosen. It's less specific.

But if you said something like:

> It reminded me of a red, very small house with a pointy tile roof I rented ...

Then your friend might have replied:

> Oh, you rented *the* Farthingworth's house ?

(No, there's probably no such place - it's just an illustration :))

She might have also said:

> Oh, you rented ***a*** Farthingworth house ?

Because the Farthingworths are quirky Oxford landowners - they paint all their houses red and put pointy roofs on them.  (Note also the implied possessive "Farthingworth house".)

Comment: "a" is indefinite, but the nature of the indefiniteness is indefinite! If you say "a house I rented", that could mean that you rented many houses and this was one of them, or it could mean that there are many houses out there in the world (or in Oxford in this case) and you rented one of them.

Comment: @Jay hmmm, yes - thought I'd covered those examples, at least implicitly, but, now as you mention it, the coverage is indefinite. :))

Comment: @Howard Just to make sure... I mean Sarah knows nothing of my life in Oxford and about Karl's house. I'm trying to figure those tricky cases in English when you use the definite article and yet for a listener, it's new information  so no shared knowledge no first mention. It's called postmodification as far as I know and works only with prepositional  and relative clauses

Comment: @Jay this mean **the** is not really possible in this case?

Comment: @dunno it's always easiest to say what you really mean and be specific enough to get that meaning across without relying on subtle grammar. In all languages, people speak plainly (unless they are lawyers or politicians :-P )

Comment: @HowardPautz  haha If I didn't rely on English grammar you wouldn't get of the gist of what I say :D Russian has no articles, no word order.

Comment: @HowardPautz Didn't mean to imply that you didn't cover that case -- you did -- I just thought that maybe an additional clarification would be helpful.

Comment: @Dunno No, you could use "the", if your intended meaning is that this is the only house you rented, or the only house you rented in Oxford. The point is that when you use the indefinite article, by itself it often does not tell the reader just what is indefinite about it. It may be clear from the context and it may not. If it's an important point, then you may need to spell it out.

Comment: Definitely a good point about indefinite :)) @Dunno form what Jay points out immediately above, there's also "the house" meaning the *only* house - not likely in Oxford. In that case saying "rented a house in Oxford" would show that the speaker was unaware that there was only one.  Obscure. RE Russian word order *ugh* that's one of the reasons I have aspirin bottles handy when I try to learn that lovely language... :))